# Hypersurfaces without real points

Tags: real-algebraic-geometry

Let $n, d$ be positive integers. I am interested in the open subset 
$\mathcal U_{n,d} \subset \mathbb P H^0 ( \mathbb P^n_{\mathbb R}, \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n_{\mathbb R}}(d))$ corresponding to sections  without real zeros. When $d$ is odd and $n$  arbitrary, the set 
 $\mathcal U_{n,d}$ is empty  since (homeogeneous) polynomials of odd degree always have (non-trivial) real roots.

> **Question.** Suppose $d$ is even. How many connected components $\mathcal U_{n,d}$ has 
>   ? Do we know anything about
>   the Betti numbers of  $\mathcal  U_{n,d}$  ?

Indeed, motivated by this other [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/58000/polynomial-contact-structures-on-rp3), I am trying to figure out if it makes sense
to ask for the number of connected components of the space of polynomial contact 
distributions of even degree on $\mathbb P^{2n+1}_{\mathbb R}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $s$ is a non-zero section whose image lies in $\mathcal U_{n,d}$, then it has constant sign on $V^\ast:=\mathbb R^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}$ and after possibly multiplying by $-1$ we may assume that $s$ is strictly positive on $V^\ast$. The strictly positive $s$ form an open convex cone $C$ (we do not assume that $0$ belongs to a cone) and is hence contractible when non-empty which this one is when $d$ is even. As $C\to\mathcal U_{n,d}$ is a fibration with fibres $\mathbb R_+$ so is $\mathcal U_{n,d}$.

Comment: @Torsten: the point is not that $C$ is a cone, but that it is convex.

Comment: Cones in my definition are always convex $u,v\in C,\lambda,\mu\in\mathbb R_+\implies \lambda u+\mu v\in C$.

Comment: Of course what I call cones should really be called convex cones but it seems that I acquired the habit of calling them cones from toric geometry.